# Question related to Banach algebra

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, self-learning, banach-algebras

My professor assigned me this exercise:

Let $D\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a *diagonal* matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 &  & \\
& \ddots &  \\
& & \lambda_n
\end{pmatrix}

for some $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$. Find $e^D$. Here in order to find $e^D$ I need to use this theorem:

**Th.** Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $A\in \mathcal{L}(X)$, then the series $e^A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}A^n$ converges in $\mathcal{L}(X)$ (here $\mathcal{L}(X)$ is Banach algebra).

Can somebody explain to me what do I need to do in this task? Maybe just calculate the determinant of D and find a limit of this series?

Comment: Why do you need the determinant? First find what is $\frac{1}{n!}A^n$ in this case, and then sum over all values of $n$. This is not going to be difficult.

Comment: Use that convergence of matrices is entrywise!

Comment: If you fix a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ you get $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n) = \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ the set of $n \times n$ matrixes. In your theorem you can replace $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n) $ by $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ which is indeed a Banach algebra. Now you need to prove a matrix is continuous, do you know what does it mean?